# Error "Application defined or object defined error" in Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

This code loops twice, then stops with an error "Application defined or object defined error"

```
Sub addsheet()
Dim Copyrange As String
Dim Copyrange2 As String
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox lastRow
Dim newsheet
Set newsheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=xlWorksheet)
newsheet.Name = "Consol"
Startrow = 1
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value)
 For i = Startrow To lastRow
        For j = 1 To 1
            Worksheets("Consol").Cells(i, j) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value
        Next j
        Next i

    Let Copyrange = "B" & Startrow & ":" & "F" & lastRow
     Let Copyrange2 = "A1" & ":" & "E" & lastRow
     Worksheets("Consol").Range(Copyrange).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Copyrange2).Value
     Columns("E").Delete
     Startrow = Startrow + lastRow
     lastRow = lastRow + lastRow
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: yes so it will only stay in column 1..

Comment: Then you don't need that loop if you're just going down one column XD

Comment: So just change `j` to `1` and remove the loop.

Comment: is that the 1 causing the error ? but it loops twice before it says the error so i guess j = 1 to 1 is working fine

Comment: It helps if you pinpoint which line throws the error.

Comment: oh i didnt know that :D

Comment: Is there anything in Column F? Which sheet is active when you start the Sub?

Comment: ^ yea, you're inconsistent with your qualifications. Also consider throwing in `debug.print` into the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting your error because you aren't meeting the exit condition for the loop before it executes the maximum of 21 times (and subsequently overflows the number of rows in an Excel sheet).  You properly have `lastRow` set as a `Long`, so the *variable* doesn't overflow, but this line of code...

```
lastRow = lastRow + lastRow
```

...**doubles** the row count you are trying to address each time through the loop.  The application error happens when you try to access a cell in a row higher than the maximum of 1048576.  So, if you start with a lastRow of 1, it will double 21 times before it is higher than 1048576.  If you start with more than 1 row, it goes a lot quicker.

I haven't examined your code much further than that, but you likely just need to use a different row counter inside the loop:

**Untested:**

```
Startrow = 1
Dim currentEnd As Long
currentEnd = lastRow
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value)
    For i = Startrow To currentEnd
        Worksheets("Consol").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value
    Next i

    Copyrange = "B" & Startrow & ":" & "F" & lastRow
    Copyrange2 = "A1" & ":" & "E" & lastRow
    Worksheets("Consol").Range(Copyrange).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Copyrange2).Value
    Columns("E").Delete
    lastRow = currentEnd + lastRow
    Startrow = lastRow
Loop
```